# How to hide a Pocket Internet Explorer element?

Tags: .net, javascript, windows-mobile

How can I hide an element in html on Pocket Internet Explorer running on a Windows Mobile 6 device. The following code does not work even though it apears to be setting the values correctly.

```
function ShowCollapseElement(sLinkId, sContentId)
    {
    var oLinkElement;
    var oContentElement;

    //Get the elements
    oLinkElement = document.getElementById(sLinkId);
    oContentElement = document.getElementById(sContentId);

    //Toggle the visibility of the content
    oContentElement.style.display = (oContentElement.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : 'inline');

    //Set the link text
    oLinkElement.innerText = (oContentElement.style.display != 'none' ? '-' : '+');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered that the code works when the element is a div, but not with a table row. I will have to settle for using a div.